# Github: Wiki page title from markup not filename/web client

Tags: github, markdown, restructuredtext, gollum-wiki

Is there a way in github to have a wiki's title be based on the markup?  I have found another project using markdown that has the title for Home.md wiki page come from the file.  The author could have also used the web interface and made the title of the page the same as the markdown.  That project is here:

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki

When I tried doing the same thing with restructuredtext (Home.rest) using the underline of ='s the title ends up being ignored and not even shown in the rendered page.  The same thing also happens when using markdown.

Comment: Do you use underlines of equal signs to signify section headers as well as your document title? Also, the extension of reStructuredText files tend to be `.rst`, not `.rest`. Perhaps changing that will make a difference.

Comment: Github defaults to .rest when you change the web client's format.  I have manually changed it to .rst (I prefer this too) and nothing changed.  I used equal signs for ONLY the title, other characters for sections and sub-sections.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at [this pull request](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/308) from a few months ago and the related discussion, it appears that the page title *used* to be set based on the markdown, but is now based exclusively on the filename.

That would explain why a project might have RestructuredText/Markdown that appears to define the title (*it once did!*), but the same doesn't work for you.

It appears that you're out of luck for defining the wiki page title through the RestructuredText/MarkDown file these days.

Comment: I hate you for being right. So lame. I will be back to award you the points and accept your answer.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich You've got 6 days left on the bounty, so no rush to make the question look settled after paying for extra publicity.  Who knows, maybe someone else will stop by with a sooper-sekrit hack, or some incredibly elegant workaround.